# Flyway revert migration validation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, flyway

So, I just read and learnt about migrations in `Flyway`.
I developed a `spring-boot` project and included `Flyway` in the projects POM file.

Now I wrote a `SQL` script in a file and put it in the `resources/db` folder of the project and `Flyway` seems to do its job.

Sadly the `SQL` script has some errors and the project won't compile. Instead it gives me a `SQL` error. After that i change my `SQL` script and resolved my errors. When I run the same project it now throws an error saying that `validation checksum failed`. I checked back the `flyway_schema_history` and it shows me the previous run script.

Shouldn't `Flyway` store only those migrations which are correct and run properly? Because if by mistake I have some errors in a `SQL` script, i will have to make one script and copy my corrected `SQL` code in that and run it. Is there anything like this present in `Flyway`?

Answer (score 1):

`Flyway`s purpose is to control the versions of your database. This is only possible with the help of strict versioning rules, like every published version gets stored with a matching checksum. Once a version is published, it cannot just be deleted or manipulated because this would effect the database status.

The `validation checksum failed` error `Flyway` prints you is exactly the effect of manipulating an existing and versioned SQL file.

However - there are some options to revert the faulty SQL file:

- Undo the last migration:

> So go ahead and invoke
>
> `flyway undo` This will give you the following result:
>
> `Database: jdbc:h2:file:./foobardb (H2 1.4) Current version of schema
>   "PUBLIC": 2 Undoing migration of schema "PUBLIC" to version 2 - Add
>   people Successfully undid 1 migration to schema "PUBLIC" (execution
>   time 00:00.030s)`

(https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/undo#undoing-the-last-migration)

- If you are still in a early testing phase, you can also delte the complete database and start with a fresh one...

Comment: or just drop the database schema and use `spring.flyway.schemas=YOURSCHEMA` in your `application.properties` to always create the database schema if it's not existing

Comment: you know what might be the better solution? `flyway:repair`. Just did it and it worked like charm.